# Generating a multiplication table with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to generate a multiplication table with T-SQL in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and have been stuck on cases where width is greater than height. As long as it does not hold, all goes well but any time Height is greater, all the cells with indices greater than the last from the height value are NULL... Why is that so and how could I overcome this?

It just generates the square matrix for values up to Height from my understanding but I'm not really sure how to fix it...

```
DECLARE @InitialValue int, @Height int, @Width int, @ColumnNames varchar(max), @RowNames varchar(max), @sql varchar(max);
SET @InitialValue = 2;
SET @Height = 2
SET @Width = 5

SELECT
    @RowNames = COALESCE(@RowNames + ', ', '')
              + '[' + CAST(@InitialValue + number AS varchar) + ']'
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
  AND number BETWEEN 0 AND @Height-2;

SELECT
    @ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ', ', '')
              + '[' + CAST(@InitialValue + number AS varchar) + ']'
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
  AND number BETWEEN 0 AND @Width-2;


SET @sql =
'WITH numbers AS (
  SELECT ' + CAST(@InitialValue AS varchar) + ' + number AS X
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE type = ''P''
    AND number BETWEEN 0 AND ' + CAST(@Height-2 AS varchar) +'
),
products AS (
  SELECT
    n1.X,
    PivotN = n2.X,
    P = n1.X * n2.X
  FROM numbers n1
    CROSS JOIN numbers n2
)
SELECT
  X, ' + @ColumnNames + '
FROM products
PIVOT (MAX(P) FOR PivotN IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')) p';
EXEC(@sql);
```

OUT:

```
X   2   3   4   5
2   4   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: What do you want as a result? Show us matrix for height 3 and width 5 for example

Comment: Do some research on creating a comma delimited string in TSQL. What you're doing is rather suspect. Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really look at your code, I just wrote my own and it works for any height or width. Check it out:

```
DECLARE @InitialValue INT = 1,
        @Height INT = 1,
        @Width INT  = 5,
        @PivotColumns VARCHAR(MAX);
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##NumsTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##numsTable;

CREATE TABLE ##NumsTable (num INT PRIMARY KEY);

WITH CTE_Nums
AS
(
    SELECT @InitialValue AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM CTE_Nums
    WHERE num <=        CASE
                        WHEN @Height > @Width
                            THEN @Height
                        ELSE @Width
                    END
)

INSERT INTO ##numsTable
    SELECT num
    FROM CTE_Nums
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(num)
FROM ##numsTable
WHERE num < @InitialValue + @Width;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL = 
N'WITH CTE_crossJoin
AS
(
SELECT  A.num           AS rowNums,
        B.num           AS colNums,
        A.num * B.num   AS result
FROM ##numsTable A
CROSS JOIN ##numsTable B
WHERE       A.num < @IV + @H
        AND B.num < @IV+ @W
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_crossJoin
PIVOT
(
    MAX(result) FOR colNums IN (' + @pivotColumns + ')
) pvt'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,N'@IV INT,@H INT,@W INT', @IV = @initialValue,@H = @Height,@W = @Width
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different version:

```
declare @InitialValue int = 2, @Height int = 10, @Width int = 10;
declare @cols varchar(4000), @f varchar(4000), @s varchar(4000);

with cols as(select @InitialValue as w
            union all 
            select w + 1 from cols where w < @InitialValue + @Width - 1)

select 
      @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' + convert(varchar(10), w) FROM cols FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 2, '') + ']',
      @f = 'case when h.h = 1 then ''X'' else cast(h.h as char(10)) end,' + 
              STUFF((SELECT '],h.h*s.[' + convert(varchar(10), w) FROM cols FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 2, '') + ']'

set @s = 'with height as (
            select 1 as h
            union all 
            select h + 1 from height where h < ' + CAST(@Height as varchar(10)) +           
            '),
width as(select ' + CAST(@InitialValue as varchar(10)) + ' as w
            union all 
            select w + 1 from width where w < ' + CAST(@InitialValue + @Width - 1 as varchar(10)) +'),
spread as(select * from width pivot(max(w) for w in(' + @cols + ')) p)                      
select ' + @f + ' 
from height h
cross join spread s'

print (@s)
exec (@s)
```

Output:

**@InitialValue int = 2, @Height int = 10, @Width int = 10**

```
X   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

**@InitialValue int = 2, @Height int = 3, @Width int = 5**

```
X   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8   10
3   6   9   12  15
```

**@InitialValue int = 5, @Height int = 4, @Width int = 3**

```
X   5   6
2   10  12
3   15  18
4   20  24
```

Comment: Thank you but were you trying to run it using SQL Server 2012? Cause on my PC it outputs "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'." regarding the last from command. Am I doing something wrong trying to run it or is there something with the 2012 edition?

Comment: @Straightfw, it is because of variables been declares as varhcar(100) and that was insufficient for big array. Just change to 4000.